# how to openiddict implementation for angular application

Tags: angular, .net-core, openiddict

How to implement openiddict using .net 6 ?
and also authenticate the angular app using openiddict.

and i have one more doubt. openiddict support microsoft entityframework database or its need any separate database.

please help me.